# PHP formula needed to calculate a simple format

Tags: php

I am trying to take an amount and convert it to a units type format...

For example:

( note: don't worry about the dollar sign )

Total is $400

I need to display it as 4 * 100

Another Example

Total is $450

I need to display it as 4 * 100 |  50 * 1

So another words there are only 100 and 1 units.

I was thinking for 3 hours already and nothing seems to come to mind...Perhaps someone out there has done something similar and already know the answer?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, we're happy to assist if you are stuck with your code, but won't provide a whole answer.

Comment: I think there is a mathematical term that describes what you're looking for, but my english and math is not that well that I have it at hand. But than the second example would be expressed as `450 = 4*100 + 1*50` I assume.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not it's homework, a good place to start would be to recognize that this really isn't a "php" problem, it's a math problem.

Comment: "So another words there are only 100 and 1 units." Does this mean that those are the only type of units you're counting? So 1000 would be 10 hundreds, not 1 thousand?

Comment: @Michael - no it is not HW, just a personal project I am doing...

Comment: @John - it is both...I need PHP to pull this information out.

Comment: @John - yes only 100 and 1 no 1000...

Comment: Is there a predefined way to break up the given amount? If not, by default, I would assume it to be in powers of 10, and otherwise, whatever's leftover - this seems to align well with your provided examples - 400 = 4*100; 450 = 4*100, last 50<100, so +50*1. yes?

Comment: If that's the case, then just use for/while-loops with terminating condition when the amount considered < 100, then try next smaller unit, ie. 1 to split the remaining amount.

Comment: Because my math sucks..I didn't even think in a math approach but what I thought of was use PHP to pull the first number out so say 4 and just display that as 4 * 100 and then so on...but i know my way is definitely not the best or even practical...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoping I am not doing your homework. Try this:

```
$num = 450;
$ones = $num % 100;
$hundreds = floor($num / 100);
echo "$hundreds * 100 | $ones * 1";
```

Comment: Hey steveo - just out of curiosity, if I needed to include 1000 thousands, how would that work?

Comment: because putting $thousand = floor($num / 1000); would not work...I mean it will be 4 * 1000 but the hundreds will be messed up...for example if I had 4570...then it would show 4 * 1000 | 45 * 100..etc and that would be wrong...

Comment: Keep the chain going: `$thousands = floor($hundreds / 10); $hundreds -= $thousands * 10;`

Comment: AH..I see what you mean...thank you again for that..I just like to disect and learn any code given to me instead of just copying and pasting and not know what exactly is going on....appreciated!

Comment: I am the same way. I *must* know how things work or I can't accept using them myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple implementation

```
$amount = 450;

$hundreds = floor($amount / 100);
$ones     = $amount % 100;

$string = array();
if( $hundreds )
    $string[] = "$hundreds * 100";

if( $ones )
    $string[] = "$ones * 1";

echo implode(' | ', $string);
```

Check out the [modulus (%) operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Comment: `$string = array();` *cringe* ;)

Comment: @LongEars: Heh, yeah, good point… I started out just concat'ing a string, rather than using an array, and the name stuck around :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution which will only show the units present, you can get rid of the array/join stuff if you always need to show both units:

```
$total = 400;

$out = array();
$hundreds = floor($total / 100);
if ($hundreds) {
    $out[] = $hundreds . ' * 100';
}

$ones = $total % 100;
if ($ones) {
    $out[] = $ones . ' * 1';
}

echo join(' | ', $out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulus operator to break down the number (this kind of thing is good to learn how to do because you'll need it for many other units conversion tasks like seconds -> minutes & seconds conversion):

```
$value=450;
$ones = $value % 100;
$hundreds = floor($value / 100);
echo "$hundreds * 100 | $ones * 1\n";
```